# System.Reflection

Tags: c#-3.0

I developed an application named as AAA in that application im referring an assembly named as BBB. At certain condition im loading that BBB assemby into my application using Assembly.LoadFromFile() function. Now i need to access certain object instances of AAA in BBB assembly at run time.Is it possible to accomplish this task? 
Thanks in Advance .

Comment: How do you invoke functions from the BBB assembly? Can you just pass your AAA objects into it?

Comment: You should accept one of these answers or at least provide feed back :)

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to create new instances of your objects? If so, this should work:

```
Assembly ass = Assembly.LoadFrom("BBB.dll");
Object myObject = ass.CreateInstance("BBB.MyObject");
```

Note this assumes that your object has a default constructor - if you need to pass parameters into the constructor, you can do something like this (assuming a constructor which takes a string as its argument):

```
Assembly ass = Assembly.LoadFrom("BBB.dll");
Type t= ass.GetType("MyObject");
ConstructorInfo c = t.GetConstructor(new Type[]{typeof(string)});
Object myObject2 = c.Invoke(new object[] { "myParam" }
```

Answer (score 0):

**Let AAA hand a reference to the object to some variable in BBB after it has loaded.**

To access object ooo from BBB, you should provide BBB with a (possibly indirect) reference to ooo. AAA may use reflection to discover the appropriate entry point for BBB and then provide it with ooo.